# PostGIS ST_AsMVTGeom disable simplification

Tags: postgis, vector-tiles

Is there a way to disable the geometry simplification when using the `ST_AsMVTGeom()` function in PostGIS? I'm generating tiles for zoom level 9 and overzoom them.

This is how it looks like when the z9 tile is overzoomed:

[image: overzoomed z9 tile]

This is how I would like the overzoomed tile to look like (tile rendered for z19, not overzoomed):

[image: tile rendered for z19]

Here is the SQL snippet I'm using to generate the tiles

```
ST_AsMVTGeom (
     ST_Transform(c.geometry, 3857) -- transform geometry to 3857: SRID Web Mercator
    ,ST_TileEnvelope($1, $2, $3)    -- tile bounds
    ,4096   -- tile extent size in tile coordinate space
    ,0      -- buffer size in tile coordinate space for geometry clippig
    ,false  -- false means do not clip the geometry, encoded as-is
) as geom
```

I'm using `Postgis v3.3 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1` and `PostgreSQL 14.6, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit`.

Comment: The tile space is only 4096 by 4096 integer numbers. That leads into simplification that gets more obvious with overzoom.

Comment: what is your api? and what do you mean by overzoom?

Comment: @user30184, so coordinates are rounded, which leads to the simplification? Could enlarging the tile space improve this?

Comment: @ziggy it's a webapp using maplibre-gl-js (fork of mapbox-gl-js) library/API. Overzooming is when you zoom into a tile without loading new tiles. See https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/overzoom/

Comment: See how geometries are encoded in MVT vector tiles https://docs.mapbox.com/data/tilesets/guides/vector-tiles-standards/#encoding-geometry. They use grid coordinates which are integers. Enlarging the tile space would make the step between the grid coordinates smaller. The effect is the same as zooming in to next level instead of overzooming.

Comment: @user30184 Thanks! Now I think I understand. So there is no simplification algorithm. It's multiple lat/lng edges being converted/rounded to integers make them ending up at the same x/y coordinates in the tile 4096x4096 grid. Correct?

Comment: Correct, when the https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsMVTGeom.html function is used. Users who create tiles with GDAL can continue the simplification in grid coordinates space with creation option "simplification" https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/mvt.html.

Comment: You should use pg_tileserv for the api. Works really well with postgis and any frontend with vts

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74254025/maplibre-reduce-xyz-vector-tile-requests @Humppakäräjät I saw your post in stackoverflow. I have same problem with large vector + psotgis and mablibre. May I ask, what's your simple rest server?

Comment: @Iroh it's a nest-js server, nothing GIS specific. All it does is executing the SQL query and returning 1:1 what Postgis returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up increasing the tile extent size to 16777215. With that, the tile kilobytes size didn't grow much and still is acceptable.

```
ST_AsMVTGeom (
     ST_Transform(c.geometry, 3857) -- transform geometry to 3857: SRID Web Mercator
    ,ST_TileEnvelope($1, $2, $3)    -- tile bounds
    ,16777215   -- tile extent size in tile coordinate space
    ,0      -- buffer size in tile coordinate space for geometry clippig
    ,false  -- false means do not clip the geometry, encoded as-is
) as geom
```

Result now looks much better and is acceptable for me. Even though it still is not perfect.

[image]